# linux mint 19 cinnamon cpu temerature goes crazy!

Tags: linux, linux-mint, cpu, gpu, temperature

I've just installed the mint 19 cinnamon on my acer aspire 5830TG as a second OS alongside with win7 and immediately have a very high temp readings:

```
$ sensors
coretemp-isa-0000
Adapter: ISA adapter
Package id 0:  +87.0°C  (high = +86.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)
Core 0:        +76.0°C  (high = +86.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)
Core 1:        +87.0°C  (high = +86.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)
```

with maxing out according to psensor CPU 93°C, GPU 72°C.

I only have a firefox running with 8 tabs opened. and a console. that's it.

I have already changed from xserver-xorg-video-nouveau to the recommended nvidia-driver-390 (the device is GeForce GT 540M)

It definitely doesn't look like that under the other OS, win7.
I have to keep my palms in the air in order to write this and not to burn myself.

edit:

```
System:    Host: blackstar Kernel: 4.15.0-20-generic x86_64 bits: 64 compiler: gcc v: 7.3.0 Desktop: Cinnamon 4.0.8 
           Distro: Linux Mint 19.1 Tessa base: Ubuntu 18.04 bionic 
Machine:   Type: Laptop System: Acer product: Aspire 4830TG v: V1.12 serial: <filter> 
           Mobo: Acer model: JM40_HR serial: <filter> BIOS: Acer v: 1.12 date: 08/14/2012 
Battery:   ID-1: BAT0 charge: 25.0 Wh condition: 38.4/66.6 Wh (58%) model: SANYO Li_Ion_4000mA status: Charging 
CPU:       Topology: Dual Core model: Intel Core i5-2430M bits: 64 type: MT MCP arch: Sandy Bridge rev: 7 L2 cache: 3072 KiB 
           flags: lm nx pae sse sse2 sse3 sse4_1 sse4_2 ssse3 vmx bogomips: 19155 
           Speed: 798 MHz min/max: 800/3000 MHz Core speeds (MHz): 1: 798 2: 798 3: 798 4: 798 
Graphics:  Device-1: Intel 2nd Generation Core Processor Family Integrated Graphics vendor: Acer Incorporated ALI driver: i915 
           v: kernel bus ID: 00:02.0 
           Device-2: NVIDIA GF108M [GeForce GT 540M] vendor: Acer Incorporated ALI driver: nvidia v: 390.116 bus ID: 01:00.0 
           Display: x11 server: X.Org 1.19.6 driver: modesetting,nvidia unloaded: fbdev,nouveau,vesa 
           resolution: 1024x768~60Hz, 1366x768~60Hz 
           OpenGL: renderer: GeForce GT 540M/PCIe/SSE2 v: 4.6.0 NVIDIA 390.116 direct render: Yes 
Audio:     Device-1: Intel 6 Series/C200 Series Family High Definition Audio vendor: Acer Incorporated ALI 
           driver: snd_hda_intel v: kernel bus ID: 00:1b.0 
           Sound Server: ALSA v: k4.15.0-20-generic 
Network:   Device-1: Qualcomm Atheros AR8151 v2.0 Gigabit Ethernet vendor: Acer Incorporated ALI driver: atl1c v: 1.0.1.1-NAPI 
           port: 2000 bus ID: 02:00.0 
           IF: enp2s0 state: down mac: <filter> 
           Device-2: Intel Centrino Advanced-N 6205 [Taylor Peak] driver: iwlwifi v: kernel port: 2000 bus ID: 03:00.0 
           IF: wlp3s0 state: up mac: <filter> 
           IF-ID-1: docker0 state: down mac: <filter> 
Drives:    Local Storage: total: 698.64 GiB used: 8.83 GiB (1.3%) 
           ID-1: /dev/sda vendor: Western Digital model: WD7500BPVT-22HXZT3 size: 698.64 GiB 
Partition: ID-1: / size: 96.82 GiB used: 8.83 GiB (9.1%) fs: ext4 dev: /dev/sda5 
Sensors:   System Temperatures: cpu: 70.0 C mobo: N/A gpu: nvidia temp: 66 C 
           Fan Speeds (RPM): N/A 
Info:      Processes: 208 Uptime: 40m Memory: 7.65 GiB used: 1.29 GiB (16.8%) Init: systemd runlevel: 5 Compilers: gcc: 7.3.0 
           Shell: bash v: 4.4.19 inxi: 3.0.27
```

Comment: When was the last time you cleaned the dust out of your laptop?

Comment: Not that long time ago.. about a year or so when I was changing the keyboard and upgrading RAM. Plus, as I mentioned win7 doesn't behave this way, otherwise both OSs would be affected, wouldn't they?

Comment: What processes do you have running? Can you check `htop` and ensure there isn't a process using a high amount of CPU?

Comment: @GAD3R I've tried that already http://tuxtweaks.com/2008/08/how-to-control-fan-speeds-in-ubuntu/ but got stacked at this point:    
`moor@blackstar:~$ sudo pwmconfig
# pwmconfig revision 6243 (2014-03-20)
...

/usr/sbin/pwmconfig: There are no pwm-capable sensor modules installed`

Comment: @JShorthouse I don't see anything wild going on there, just a couple of standard processes.. psensors shows max CPU load measured at 45%

Comment: @GAD3R The high fan speed (although variable) brought me to the idea of installing the fancontrol in the first place but with such a high temperature it is normal for a fan to run at higher speed and I don't want to mess around with it and lead to a hardware damage. need to fix the temp problem in the first place.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check your CPU heatsink  ! !    Mine has disengaged from the mounting brackets, same symptoms  !   Replace by a good model, select from the cpu type.

Comment: in fact I haven't checked the condition of the cooling paste since I bought it new. It will be worth trying but why everything works fine on win7 having intellij, vmbox, db servers, app server,  firefox with 1000 tabs and what not fired up still being able to rest my palms...

Comment: you were right! the paste on the gpu was dried out, the cpu though was still fine, just replaced the paste everywhere and guess what:
`Package id 0:  +41.0°C  (high = +86.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)
Core 0:        +41.0°C  (high = +86.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)
Core 1:        +40.0°C  (high = +86.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)`

was hoping to go down to something like 23-25 °C but I can live with 40 ;)
wondering why it was much colder on windows? 
Anyway thanks!

Comment: Happy to know !   I do not think that Mint is more cpu hungry than other OS,  so it can be the usage.  My system is working at 75deg, but always doing tasks for BOINC (shared computational power), limiting to 80% cpu usage max.